# Extract Content from <span class=“value ”> </div> Tag C# RegEx

Tags: c#, html, regex

I have some HTML code:

```
<div class="code">
<span class="title">desc</span>:<span class="value">'Custom text'</span>,

<div class="code">
    <span class="title">
    </span>
<div>
```

I need to get the content between `<span class="value">...</div>` tags. I tried to get - `Custom text`. How can I do it with `Regex` and `C#`?

Comment: Do you want to get only 'Custom text' or the values between every tag?

Comment: use regex as "<span class="value">(.|\n)*?</span>" and from result data replace tags and get your answer

Comment: Are you sure, you meant "</div>"? Your openening tag is span...

Answer (score 1):

You can capture in first group like:

```
<span .*? class="value".*?>([^<]+)<\/span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex:

```
<span[^>]*class=\"value\"[^>]*>([^<]*)<\/span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add runat="server" to the control of which you want to extract the data in your CS page

HTML:

```
<span class="value" id="test" runat="server">'Custom text'</span>
```

CS

```
String vl=test.InnerHtml;
```